# How to convert csv with pandas to json

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I need to convert multiple huge csv files (each 100k+ lines, 100+ rows) to JSON for further handling.
I thought of threading and splitting the csv to chunks for quicker handling but couldn't get python to read only certain lines with the built in csv library. Therefore, I thought of pandas.read_csv.
Yet, now I can't think of a performant way of converting the pandas dataframe nicely to json without killing all performance due to implementing loops..

I already have a single thread parsing the files serially. Works, is just super slow and with daily updates of the data and therefore redoing this every day it's just no fun...

```
header = next(f)
for row in f:
    data[row[0]] = dict()
    e = 0
    for element in row[1:]:
        e += 1
        if element != "":
            try:
                data[row[0]][header[e + 1]] = int(element)
            except ValueError:
                data[row[0]][header[e+1]] = element
```

The result should stay the same, just a lot faster...

```
data = pd.read_csv(file_name, skiprows=self.chunk, nrows=self.steps)
data = data.to_dict(orient="records")
```

would be my start but then nothing besides of slow loops worked till now. Data is now a list of all the rows, each row containing a dict with key from row above (not the header) and the expected value as value:

```
[{row_above_chunk[0] = row[0], row_above_chunk[1] = row[1], row_above_chunk[2] = row[2], ...}, {...}]
```

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a compound problem:

- Reading Large Datafiles
- Dumping that data to a JSON file

You can use something like this:

```
with open('DataDump.json', 'w') as file:
dfs = pd.read_csv('FilePATH.csv', chunksize=50000)
for df in dfs:
    df.to_json(file)
```

This uses `chunksize` and `df.to_json()`, further [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html).

You can change the `chunksize` to something that suits your memory capacity.